# Can't connect to the internet while others devices can

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dns

I have a laptop that duelboot windows 7 and Linux mint .
It can connect to my home network but the internet is not working .
Other devices like my smartphone can connect and access the internet.
My laptop can connect and access the internet of my neighbor's network.
After using Windows network troubleshoot it says that's the dns server doesn't respond.
The ping to 8.8.8.8 works but [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) doesn't.

Comment: What error does it show when you try to ping www.google.com? I'm assuming it's a "cannot resolve host" error or something similar to that. That's a sign of a DNS issue. Make sure you have your DNS nameservers set properly.

Comment: what are the settings on your WLAN card, what are you routers settings?